# Does PHP error_reporting(0) affect error logging, or just display?

Tags: php, error-reporting, error-logging

Does `error_reporting(0);` have any effect on error logging (to file), or does it just suppress on-screen error display?

Thanks.

Comment: This is crazy - four conflicting answers?

Comment: I know, I've tried the documentation and search engines but conflicting statements there as well.  Thanks for all input, I'm going with zombat's answer for further testing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it affects both.

The error_reporting level defines what levels of errors gets *triggered*.  Whether you log or display those errors are determined by the other settings.

To summarize:

- [error_reporting](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting): What levels of errors get triggered.
- [display_errors](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors): Whether to show triggered errors in script output.
- [log_errors](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors): Whether to write triggered errors to a log.

In essence, setting `error_reporting(0)` means that you've turned off error reporting, and nothing will be logged to file or output to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It just suppresses displayed errors. Your [ini settings for error logging](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) determine logging levels.

Answer (score -3):

PHP has pretty good docs, check out

http://us.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting
for what it does,

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
for the runtime function

Its effects depend on where stderr is going.