# Turn off display errors using file "php.ini"

Tags: php

I am trying to turn off all errors on my website. I have followed different tutorials on how to do this, but I keep getting read and open error messages. Is there something I am missing?

I have tried the following in my *php.ini* file:

```
;Error display
display_startup_errors = Off
display_errors = Off
html_errors = Off
docref_root = 0
docref_ext = 0
```

For some reason when I do a fileopen() call for a file which does not exist, I still get the error displayed. This is not safe for a live website, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Try to explicitly set it via ini_set() function in your script. However it's a bad practice and you should catch the errors and do something with them instead of hiding via display_Errors

Comment: I suggest running `grep display_errors /path/to/php.ini` to see if your line is getting overrided somewhere down the file. This is what was happening to me.

Comment: @rgajrawala your comment was the life saver for me, thank you

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I always use something like this in a configuration file:

```
// Toggle this to change the setting
define('DEBUG', true);

// You want all errors to be triggered
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(DEBUG == true)
{
    // You're developing, so you want all errors to be shown
    display_errors(true);

    // Logging is usually overkill during development
    log_errors(false);
}
else
{
    // You don't want to display errors on a production environment
    display_errors(false);

    // You definitely want to log any occurring
    log_errors(true);
}
```

This allows easy toggling between debug settings. You can improve this further by checking on which server the code is running (development, test, acceptance, and production) and change your settings accordingly.

Note that no errors will be logged if error_reporting is set to 0, as cleverly remarked by Korri.

Comment: error_reporting(0); does have an effect on logging be carefull !

Comment: @Korri is right. Refer to this answer for detailed information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911920/does-php-error-reporting0-have-any-effect-on-logging-information

Comment: Am I missing something or is `display_errors` some kind of custom function? I don't see it [in the manual](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=display_errors).

Comment: It's a runtime configuration function: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Answer (score 30):

You should consider **not displaying** your error messages instead!

Set `ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');` in your PHP code (or directly into your ini file if possible), and leave error_reporting on `E_ALL` or whatever kind of messages you would like to find in your logs.

This way you can handle errors later, while your users still don't see them.

#### Full example:

```
define('DEBUG', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (DEBUG)
{
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
}
else
{
    ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
}
```

#### Or simply (same effect):

```
define('DEBUG', true);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', DEBUG ? 'On' : 'Off');
```

Comment: Bit of an aside but I think it's preferable to set boolean values to `'1'`/`'0'`, rather than `'On'`/`'Off'`. For the simple reason that when you read the value back with `init_get()` you get the literal string that was set. `'Off'` is a non-empty string that evaluates to _True_.

Comment: It would probably make it easier, since one would be able to just write `if(ini_get('display_errors'))` (which right now would be true either way). But I actually think the check should never be done like this either way! Anyone maintaining the code could still set it to `Off` or `No` (or even `Foobar` (anything but `1`, `Yes` and `On` works as negative value)). A safe check could be for example: `$val = strtolower(ini_get('display_errors')); if ($val == '1' || $val == 'on' || $val == 'yes') ...` Still you have a very valid point, imho!

Answer (score 13):

In `php.ini`, comment out:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT
error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ER… _ERROR
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

By placing a `;` ahead of it (i.e., like `;error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`)

**For disabling in a single file**, place `error_reporting(0);` after opening a `php` tag.

Comment: Will this affect error logging? as i want errors to be logged but not displayed

Answer (score 10):

In file *php.ini* you should try this for all errors:

```
error_reporting = off
```

Comment: How to find php.ini, in console write `php -ini | less` and find the path for php.ini, or create a file.php and put inside `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Answer (score 5):

Let me quickly summarize this for reference:

- [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/error_reporting) adapts the currently active setting for the default error handler.
- Editing the [error reporting ini options](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) also changes the defaults.

  - Here it's imperative to edit the *correct* `php.ini` version - it's typically `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` on modern servers, `/etc/php5/mod_php/php.ini` alternatively; while the CLI version has a distinct one.
  - Alternatively you can use depending on SAPI:

    - mod_php: `.htaccess` with `php_flag` options
    - FastCGI: commonly a local `php.ini`
    - And with PHP above 5.3 also a `.user.ini`
  - Restarting the webserver as usual.

If your code is unwieldy and somehow resets these options elsewhere at runtime, then an alternative and quick way is to define a custom error handler that just slurps all notices/warnings/errors up:

```
set_error_handler(function(){});
```

Again, this is not advisable, just an alternative.

Comment: Nice summary, and also nice `set_error_handler` hack ^^

Comment: It may also be e.g. `/etc/opt/remi/php73/php.ini` (for PHP 7.3) on some hosting ([Red Hat Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) based?)

Answer (score 4):

In file *php.ini* you should try this for all errors:

```
display_errors = On
```

Location file is:

- Ubuntu 16.04:/etc/php/7.0/apache2
- CentOS 7:/etc/php.ini

Comment: Where is this file located?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use PHP's `error_reporting();`

```
// Disable it all for current call
error_reporting(0);
```

If you want to ignore errors from one function only, you can prepend a `@` symbol.

```
@any_function(); // Errors are ignored
```

Comment: Is this for php.ini or htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

Turn if off:

You can use [`error_reporting();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) or [put an @](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) in front of your fileopen().

Answer (score 1):

I usually use PHP's built in error handlers that can handle every possible error outside of syntax and still render a nice 'Down for maintenance' page otherwise:

*[Format PHP error on production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28928565/format-php-error-on-production-server/28928975#28928975)*

Answer (score 0):

Open your php.ini file (If you are using Linux - sudo vim /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini)

Add this lines into that file

```
   error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_WARNING
```

(If you need to disabled any other errors -> error_reporting = **E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING**)

```
    display_errors = On
```

And finally you need to restart your APACHE server.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough in case of PHP fpm. It was one more configuration file which can enable `display_error`. You should find **www.conf**. In my case it is in directory */etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/*

You should find `php_flag[display_errors] = on` and disable it, `php_flag[display_errors] = off`. This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite some time and iam sure OP's answer is cleared. If any new user still looking for answer and scrolled this far, then here it is.

### Check your updated information in php.ini file

#### Using Windows explorer:

```
C/xampp/php/php.ini
```

#### Using XAMPP Control Panel

1. Click the Config button for 'Apache' (Stop | Admin | Config | Logs)
2. Select PHP (php.ini)

#### Can i create my own phpinfo()? Yes you can

1. Create a phpinfo.php in your root directly or anywhere you want
2. Place this `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
3. Save the file.
4. Open the file and you should see all the details.

#### How to set `display_errors` to `Off` in my own file without using php.ini

You can do this using `ini_set()` function. Read more about ini_set() here (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

1. Go to your header.php or index.php
2. add this code `ini_set('display_errors', FALSE);`

#### To check the output without accessing php.ini file

```
$displayErrors = (ini_get('display_errors') == 1) ? 'On' : 'Off';
$PHPCore = array(
    'Display error' => $displayErrors
    // add other details for more output
);
foreach ($PHPCore as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value";
}
```