# Setup development enviroment for PHP development on windows

Tags: php, lamp

I need to develop a PHP application and as I am not familiar with PHP and I am working on a windows environment, I need to setup a development system. I develop normally using Visual Studio and I did some ASP.Net development so I am familiar with web development. My questions:

1- Can I develop PHP using Visual studio?

2- What is the best development setup for PHP development?

3- How can I debug PHP code?

4- Do I need a web server on my pc? If yes, is there any portable web server, where I don't need to install it?

Comment: Or you may install virtualbox and run your code there.

Comment: 1) Unknow, you can use note pad. 2)It Depends, for IDE you have a lot, like dreamweaver or phpDesigner maybe. 3) google 4)it's best to have to (at least for debug). try to search xampp portable or easyphp portable.

Answer (score 0):

1: There's a [plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5), but probably isn't the best option.

2: That's arbitrary, [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) is popular, another one is [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/).

3: Using [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/), or just by googling any error you get. Remember to setup the right [debug settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949304/turn-off-display-error-php-ini/15949445#15949445).

4: That's convenient yes. [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) (platform independent) or [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (Windows) are the most common options. Another one is [Nginx](http://nginx.org/).