# suppress all errors, warnings, Deprecated etc. messages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a very old system running with an old php version. In order to check the website i have to suppress all errors, warnings, Deprecated etc. messages. Unfortunately there a lots of `ini_set("display_errors", "1");` inside the code all over the system.

Is it possible to suppress everything no matter what a php script calls? Maybe with the php.ini or htaccess?

I already disabled "display_errors" in the php.ini. But that didnt help.

Comment: you can do it in your php.ini

Comment: @caryaritferrer then please tell the OP how

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15949483/6257039

Comment: you need to restart apache afterwards while make changes in php.ini

Comment: Please note that this question is about how to suppress errors in a legacy codebase that has hard-coded `ini_set("display_errors", "1");` calls all around. I can't see how the alleged duplicate (or editing `php.ini` altogether) addresses this use case.

Answer (score 0):

For the best error logging experience, set error_reporting to `-1`, turn `display_errors` off, and set a custom `error_log` location so it doesn't mix in with other sites you may be building.

After doing that, you should find and delete the display error ini_set() calls.

Then in the terminal, type `tail -f /path/to/error_log`. Your notices, warnings and errors will now scroll past in real time, without distorting your web page's display.

This way, you can still see what needs refactored/fixed in a much tidier log format, but without the mess all over your page!

Answer (score 0):

It don't see particularly daunting to search and comment out all `ini_set("display_errors", "1");` calls but the alternative would be write a custom error handler (or edit the existing one):

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

function ignore_errors($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    // Optional error processing
    return true;
}

$foo++;

set_error_handler('ignore_errors');

$bar++;
```

```
Notice: Undefined variable: foo in C:\...\scratch_7.php on line 11
```

If there're too many entry points, you can always call an external file with the [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive in your main `php.ini` file.