# PHP notices shown even display_errors is Off and error_reporting is 0

Tags: php, centos7, error-reporting

VmWare Cloud Server

CentOS Linux 7.6.1810 - Php 5.6.40 - Apache/2.4.6

test.php

```
<?php
  echo($x);
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Output :

**Notice: Undefined variable x in /var/www/html/test.php on line 1**

In CORE section of phpinfo output I have

**display_errors Off**

display_startup_errors Off

error_reporting 0

Why Notice is shown?

I'd like not to show any error/notice/warning etc.

Comment: Try putting `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);` after `<?php` to avoid warnings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn Off Display Error PHP.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949304/turn-off-display-error-php-ini)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your settings are controlled in the htaccess file, see more info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

But you can try this:

```php
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
echo($x);
phpinfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following at the top of your PHP script :

```
<?php error_reporting(0); ?>
```

If the notice disappears, I would suggest making sure you are modifying the good php.ini file.