# Lumen application doesn't show stacktrace while in debug mode

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have two Lumen microservices with (as far as I can tell) identical configuration. One shows a user-friendly error page, one doesn't.

Both services have this simple controller method:

```
public function test()
{
    echo $a;
    exit;
}
```

One of the services only shows:

> Oops! An Error Occurred
> The server returned a "500 Internal Server
> Error". Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing
> when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry
> for any inconvenience caused.

The other service shows the stacktrace, etc.

`APP_DEBUG=true` and `APP_ENV=local` on both environments. I verified these settings by echo'ing them in the controller method.

What setting could I be missing that prevents me from seeing the stacktrace?

Comment: do you see errors in logs? `storage/framework/logs/` I think its on this path.

Comment: the problem must be in your php.ini which does not show error  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949304/turn-off-display-errors-using-file-php-ini

Comment: Both microservices are running on the same local server with the same php.ini, and in both cases the error ends up in `laravel.log`

Comment: might be a cache issue... did you try `php artisan optimize:clear` ?

Comment: Funny by the way, you found a question that I answered 10 years ago.

Comment: `optimize:clear` doesn't exist in Lumen, but `cache:clear` does and doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252663/discussion-between-devnull--and-sherlock).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have a `config/app.php` file where the `debug` setting was missing. Adding `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),` to the array solved my issue.